Excess Return Evaluation Bias
Im currently working on a Alpha and Risk Model for constructing portfolios. From what Ive read on books and here, they are constructed in a different way and produce differents results. My Risk Model (in a statistical setting and linear world) is giving me the loadings $B$ and the factor returns $F$, so i can decompose idiosyncratic return as $\varepsilon = r - BF$.

For the Alpha model, im trying to forecast the return for next period with some learning algorithm $g$, say $r_{t+1} = g(X_t)$, but since I dont want to include systematic factors on target variable, the approach would be to use excess return for that day, i.e $\varepsilon_{t + 1} = g(X_t)$.
This make sense to me, but the problem I have, is that when constructing my target variable, i need my Risk Model to produce the residuals, so maybe the excess return evaluation is biased on the results of my Risk Model and not independent of it. If i select only few factors, $g$ is learning a systematic structure and noise with selecting a lot of them.
Is this approach correctly and this 2 models interact before Portfolio Optimization or im missing something here?
Thanks in advance

Not sure how your learning algorithm works, but technically one can treat the idio returns as a separate time series (although you are right, it does depend on the factor returns as well). How I understand it is that the learning algorithm should predict the future excess returns based on the time series patterns of the idio returns and not the contribution from the factors themselves.

@KaiSqDist I understand that approach (ex: basic AR(1) with only excess returns, so Risk Model affects construction of target and regressors). But for this case, the matrix X dont need to be residuals, it could be any feature independent of systematic risk and $g$ could be any ML or time series model that use exogenous regressors, hence, Risk Modek only affecting target $\varepsilon$

Yes, it really comes down to what you want.
